# tableView dataSource and delegate restrictions

Tags: ios, uitableview

Why does tableView on iOS needs "numberOfRowsInSection" and "cellForRowAtIndexPath" functions to run well when it's dataSource connected to View Controller?

Comment: How else would the table know how many rows there are and how would it be able to populate the table with cells if you didn't implement the required data source methods?

Comment: So even though I added some prototypes, it still needs to know how many rows there are on the view?

Comment: Are you creating a normal table view or a static table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways how you can put rows into a UITableViewController:

`variable` or `static`

*Care, `static` can only be used when you are using an UITableViewController and not just a UITableView*

`static` means is that you specify when you write the app which exact rows are in your table, this is a special case and usually used for settings etc.

The more common case is that you don't actually know which exact rows will be displayed since you load data from the internet and display this data depending on what is actually loaded.

From your question it sounds like you are looking for the static approach, in which case you actually don't need these methods, **BUT** I would in general avoid using the `static` tableView since if this ever changes you will have to do extra work to transfer it.